# Speed camera check: finding user time

Tags: python

I am currently writing a speed camera check program that records the time taken for the driver to pass two sensors.

I want to find the user's average speed by using speed = distance/time

With a speed camera, the distance is known but the time isn't. Here's some of my code.

```
distanceapart = 20
start = input("Press enter to start")
starttime =(datetime.now())
stop = input("Press enter to stop")
stoptime =(datetime.now())

time = stoptime-starttime
```

This is to record the user's time.

One of the outputs is
    '0:00:00.451445 seconds'

I have tried

```
distanceapart/time
```

But it doesn't work

Is there anyway to make this work?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you want to happen? For example, what would your expected output be for the time you gave?

Comment: You can't convert and int by a `datetime` object. Convert to for instance to seconds first. Secondly what is dsitance? `km/m`

Comment: @Ludisposed The distance is metres

Comment: have a look into the datetime documentation - you need something that gives you the total amount in seconds https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects or some kind of timedelta with totalseconds ...

Comment: @pycoder - i want to workout the user's average speed using 'distance/time' equation. Also, I'm still new to python as well.

Comment: Speed is distance/time but you say "it doesn't work". Why not? Did you enter that equation on a line of its own? (Which indeed would not work; it's a syntax error.)

Comment: Yes, but from what i've learnt, you can't really divide by a 'timedelta', hence why it wasn't working when I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a dedicated precision timer for that:

```
import sys
import time

# a cross-platform precision timer
get_timer = time.clock if sys.platform == "win32" else time.time

distance = 20
input("Press enter to start.")
start_time = get_timer()
input("Press enter to stop.")
stop_time = get_timer()

delta_time = stop_time - start_time  # passed time in seconds
speed = distance / delta_time  # the unit depends on the unit of your `distance` value
```

Comment: I understand most of it, but not the 3rd line 'get_timer'... can you please explain?

Comment: @1ndy123 the built-in `time` module has two functions for precision timers - [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.clock) and [`time.time()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.time) (you can read more on different Python timers at [this page](https://www.webucator.com/blog/2015/08/python-clocks-explained/)). Unfortunately, they behave differently on different platforms and for Windows the former one is preferred. That line just stores a reference to the more precise function in dependence of the platform to the `get_timer` variable.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between start and end gives a [timedelta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object. You need to access the time difference using one of the class fields of the timedelta like this.

```
from datetime import datetime
start = datetime.now()
end = datetime.now()
delta = end - start
distance = 20
speed = distance / delta.seconds
# 4.0 distance units / second
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
import datetime
import time # for sleep 

dt = datetime.datetime.now()   # one now()
time.sleep(1.83)
dt2 = datetime.datetime.now()  # another now() a bit later


dtdelta = dt2-dt               # time spent (it is a deltatime)
print( dtdelta.total_seconds()) # in total_seconds   - use it to calculate your speed
```

Dokumentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime